# netbeans 8.0 incorrect credentials to repository using ssh

Tags: java, netbeans, ssh

When I try to connect to my EC2 server, using Netbeans(Git-Remote-Push), I get *"incorrect credentials coonecting to repository at SSH://xx.xx.xxx.xx/git-repo"*

In my ide.log, I get the following message:

*"WARNING [org.netbeans.modules.progress.spi.InternalHandle]: Cannot call progress on a task that was never started at org.netbeans.modules.git.client.GitProgressSupport.setProgressMessage(GitProgressSupport.java:247)
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.git.ui.repository.remote.SelectUriStep]: Auth failed when accessing ssh://54.77.226.97/git-repo
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Algorithm negotiation fail"*

Steps I have taken to overcome the problem.

1. I can connect using git-bash OK
2. I have ussed ssh-keygen to generate the keys
3. I have downloaded JCE 8 unlimited strength policy files.

Any help much appreciated, thanks

Comment: What does "Algorithm negotiation fail" mean to you?  Sounds like an incompatibility between the SSH configuration on your end and the server.

Answer (score 1):

"Algorithm negotiation fail" means that the SSH-Client implementation netbeans uses and the server implementation, cannot find a mutual algorithm to encrypt/compress.

Reason could be that an administrator doesn't want the server to support insecure or doubtful algorithms from now on. So you have to find an update for Netbeans.